# Put files through a several step process ONE AT A TIME in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Sorry if this is a big face palm for you guys. I'm a beginner, just trying to save some time.

I have some .bnk files that I'd like to run through a few steps to extract the audio out of the files. My problem is, the extracted files overwrite each other as they are created and I'm trying to get the extracted files into it's own folder.

Here's my current batch file:

```
FOR %%a IN ("Game Files\*.BNK") DO (MD "%%~na" 2>nul) 
FOR %%b IN ("Game Files\*.BNK") DO ("Tools\bnkextr.exe" "%%b" & MOVE *.wav "Tools\Decoding")
FOR %%c IN (Tools\Decoding\*.WAV) DO ("Tools\ww2ogg.exe" "%%c" --pcb Tools\packed_codebooks_aoTuV_603.bin & DEL "%%c")
FOR %%d IN (Tools\Decoding\*.OGG) DO ("Tools\revorb.exe" "%%d" & MOVE "%%a" "%%~na")
FOR %%f IN ("Game Files\*.BNK") DO (DEL "%%f")
echo BNK files deleted, enjoy your unpacked audio!
pause 
exit
```

I have multiple .bnk files in the \Game Files\ folder, for example:

```
GameSoundFX.bnk
GameMusic.bnk
```

The first line of my code creates a new folder based on the filename of the .bnk.

```
FOR %%a IN ("Game Files\*.BNK") DO (MD "%%~na" 2>nul)
```

The next three lines puts the .bnk through a series of extraction and codec processes. First it creates multiple .wav files and then it converts them in to .ogg files. I'd like it to then move those .ogg files into the relevant folder so I end up with something like this..

```
\GameSoundFX\0001.ogg
\GameSoundFX\0002.ogg
\GameSoundFX\0003.ogg
\GameMusic\0001.ogg
\GameMusic\0002.ogg
\GameMusic\0003.ogg
```

But the problem is...

1) the first line creates all the folders first

2) the second line creates all the .wav files (and .wav files from the second .bnk file overwrite the first)

3) the fourth line doesn't move the files into the correct folder. they remain in \Tools\Decoding\

So, I guess my question is, how can I get this batch file to run through the process with each .bnk file ONE AT A TIME and then place the .ogg files into the folder we create with the first line of code?

Comment: For each source file, call a subroutine that does each of the steps. You only need one loop with multiple steps in the body. `for %%a ... do call :ProcessFile %%a`. See `help call`, `help exit`.

Comment: Nest the steps so that it does not process another BNK file until it is done creating the WAV and OGG files first.  You basically have way over coded your task.

Comment: You also have a problem with this line of code: `"Tools\revorb.exe" "%%d" & MOVE "%%a" "%%~na"`.  You are using the wrong `FOR` variable. %%a no longer exists.  You used that with your first `FOR` command.  Did you mean to use %%d?

Comment: And I guess my last question is you make a directory with the base file name of the BNK file but you do not use that directory in your code.  So I am not sure what files you want moved into the directory you created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid multi-command blocks/lines of code (nesting, `&` and `&&`) where possible. It makes things easier to follow when debugging and it's just plain easier to get it right the first time.

Untested:

```
@setlocal EnableExtensions

@set _decodingDir=Tools\Decoding
@for %%I in ("Game Files\*.BNK") do @call :ProcessBNK "%%I"
@exit /b

:ProcessBNK
@set _targetDir="%~n1"
@md %_targetDir% 2>nul
@Tools\bnkextr.exe %1
@move *.wav %_decodingDir%
@for %%I in (%_decodingDir%\*.WAV) do @call :ProcessWAV "%%I"
@for %%I in (%_decodingDir%\*.OGG) do @Tools\revorb.exe "%%I"
@move %_decodingDir%\*.ogg %_targetDir%
@move %1 %_targetDir%
@exit /b

:ProcessWAV
@Tools\ww2ogg.exe %1 --pcb Tools\packed_codebooks_aoTuV_603.bin
@del %1
@exit /b
```

Remove leading `@` symbol to show lines when debugging (assumes echo is on in your command window).

Comment: This is amazing. It almost works. 

It created the folder.. 

It extracted the .wav files. They were processed into .ogg files.

But then, the .bnk was moved into the _targetDir

The .ogg files remain in \tools\decoding\

Comment: Where do you want the .ogg and .bnk files to wind up?

Comment: `move %1 %_targetDir%` is the line that moves the .bnk files one at a time after they've been processed.

Comment: @Slynk, I updated script to fix the .ogg file bug. You did want those moved from the decoding directory into the target directory yes?

Comment: I fixed it. I just changed it to move Tools\Decoding\*.OGG %_targetDir%

Comment: @Slynk, if you nest this line of code: `@move %_decodingDir%\*.ogg %_targetDir%` inside the previous `FOR` command you can rename the OGG file at the same time.

Comment: I always avoid nesting and concatenating execution of multiple commands on a single line. It makes maintenance and debugging more difficult. And yes, they could be moved one at a time, but it's not necessary, so I didn't create a subroutine for processing the .ogg files. Why make it more complicated?

Comment: @jwdonahue, my previous comment relates to his other question he started.  If you look at my code, when moving the OGG file all you have to do is change this line: `MOVE "%%d" "%%~na"` to this: `MOVE "%%d" "%%~na\%%~na - %%~nxd"` and the file is renamed to how he wants it in his other question.  Regardless I think your choice to not use nested `FOR` and `IF` commands, really handicaps you from making the code more efficient.  Using the CALL command creates more overhead.

Comment: @Squashman, have you ever measured the execution times between the `...do (nested code)` and the `do call :procedure`? How much time do we spend helping newbs workout what's wrong with their use or failure to use delayed expansion?  I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: @jwdonahue, do you see any of my code using delayed expansion?

Comment: @Squashman, in this particular case, no. But I still discourage anyone who will listen, from using multi-line command blocks or concatenating commands on a single line whenever it can be avoided. I've spent too many hours trying to debug that style of batch scripting. I have learned to adopt a style that is more easily composable and debug-able. I think it's easier to read as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily nest your commands to make sure it processes one file at a time. When you nest commands inside parenthesesized code blocks it helps to indent the code so you know what belongs to what.  I am unsure what some of your code is doing and I made a comment in my code accordingly.  See if this helps.

```
@ECHO off
FOR %%a IN ("Game Files\*.BNK") DO (
    MD "%%~na" 2>nul
    Tools\bnkextr.exe" "%%a"
    MOVE *.wav "Tools\Decoding"
    FOR %%c IN (Tools\Decoding\*.WAV) DO (
        "Tools\ww2ogg.exe" "%%c" --pcb Tools\packed_codebooks_aoTuV_603.bin
        DEL "%%c"
    )
    FOR %%d IN (Tools\Decoding\*.OGG) DO (
        "Tools\revorb.exe" "%%d"
        REM ##### Unsure what you are trying to move here ####
        MOVE "%%d" "%%~na"
    )
    REM Deleting the .BNK file
    DEL "%%a"
)
pause 
exit
```

Comment: There were a couple of bugs in the OP's original code. Moving the BNK file then trying to delete them is one of them.

Comment: @jwdonahue, I am not sure he was trying to move the BNK files or he really wanted to move the OGG files.  I assume the OGG files because he has code to delete the BNK.

Comment: In `FOR %%d IN (Tools\Decoding\*.OGG) DO ("Tools\revorb.exe" "%%d" & MOVE "%%a" "%%~na")`, the OP was trying to move the bnk files, but failing due to %%a being out of scope. Not sure why the OP also tried to delete them, probably a bug.

Comment: @jwdonahue, yes that is why I made the comment below his question and I also put a comment in my code.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks jwdonahue!

Your code almost worked. I just had to adjust a little bit because the .ogg files remained in \Tools\Decoding. I tested it with multiple .bnk files in \Game Files\ and it worked! Thankyou so much.

```
setlocal EnableExtensions

for %%I in ("Game Files\*.BNK") do call :ProcessBNK "%%I"
exit /b

:ProcessBNK
set _targetDir="%~n1"
md %_targetDir% 2>nul
Tools\bnkextr.exe %1
move *.wav Tools\Decoding
for %%I in (Tools\Decoding\*.WAV) do call :ProcessWAV "%%I"
for %%I in (Tools\Decoding\*.OGG) do Tools\revorb.exe "%%I"
move Tools\Decoding\*.OGG %_targetDir%
move %1 %_targetDir%
exit /b

:ProcessWAV
Tools\ww2ogg.exe %1 --pcb Tools\packed_codebooks_aoTuV_603.bin
del %1
exit /b
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Since decoding directory is used in so many places I also added a variable for it. You should accept somebody's answer other than your own, except when no one gave an answer that was acceptable of course.

Comment: Since this is duplicate answer, you should just delete it. @Slynk

Comment: @Slynk, you don't answer youf question after someone gave you an answer.  That is in poor taste.